# Zull + Eureka (same application) + oauth (external service)

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm currently trying to build an application with Zuul + Eureka, using spring boot, running on port 9000. Everything works fine until I bring up @EnableOAuth2Sso to the application. From that moment on, no service (not even the Zuul + Eureka application itself) can register to Eureka anymore.

When I try to access `http://localhost:9000`, the browser shows me the login page, I enter my dummy user credentials (user, password) and I can see Eureka's dashboard, showing no client registered (as shown in the images at the bottom of this question).

Can anyone point me any direction to go? I think I could tell the Zuul + Eureka security part to permit all requests to Eureka, but I don't know how to do it.

My application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 9000

logging:
  level:
    com:
      netflix:
        eureka: OFF
        discovery: OFF

eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:9000/eureka/
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true

security:
  sessions: ALWAYS
  basic.enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientId: acme
      clientSecret: acmesecret
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
      jwt:
        keyValue: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          #here goes my public key
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

My annotaded application class:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've secured the eureka server. I'd suggest using `@EnableEurekaServer` on a separate application.

Comment: @spencergibb, I'm trying to save memory (Springboot applications consume a lot of memory). Is there anyway to force the security to ignore requests to Eureka (at least the ones to register the applications)?